# Batch Script - How to get variable value using a different variable that has the variable name stored

Tags: batch-file

I'm having trouble access the value stored in the example below.  I need to access the value stored in a variable, but the variable name is stored in a different variable. Please help.

Example:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set a222333password=hellopass

for %%i in (%fileserver%\t*) do ( 
  set currentfilename=%%~ni --> file name is "t222333"
  set currentlogin=!currentfilename:t=a!  --> login is "a222333"
  set currentpasswd=!!currentlogin!password! --> password should be "hellopass"
  echo !currentpasswd!  --> this gives me the value "a222333password" instead of "hellopass"

)
```

Comment: This type of management is explained at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), although the topic is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest delayed expansion like `set currentpasswd=!!currentlogin!password!`, because this first detects `!!`, which are combined to one opening `!`, so the variable expansion `!currentlogin!` is done resulting in `a222333`, then there is the literal part `password`, and finally another `!` that cannot be paired and is therefore ignored.

However, you could try this, because `call` initiates another parsing phase:

```cmd
call set "currentpasswd=%%!currentlogin!password%%"
```

Or this, because `for` variable references become expanded before delayed expansion occurs:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%Z in ("!currentlogin!") do set "currentpasswd=!%%Zpassword!"
```

Or also this, because argument references, like normally expanded variables (`%`-expansion), are expanded before delayed expansion is done:

```cmd
rem // Instead of `set currentpasswd=!!currentlogin!password!`:
call :SUBROUTINE currentpasswd "!currentlogin!"

rem // Then, at the end of your current script:
goto :EOF

:SUBROUTINE
set "%~1=!%~2password!"
goto :EOF

rem // Alternatively, when you do not want to pass any arguments to the sub-routine:
:SUBROUTINE
set "currentpasswd=!%currentlogin%password!"
goto :EOF
```

All these variants have got two important things in common:

1. there occur two expansion phases;
2. the inner variable reference is expanded before the outer one;