# Dynamic variable name in cmd.exe w/ command extensions

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, variable-expansion

I see this is a common theme, but I believe I have a unique problem.

I want to use this technique of variable expansion, where you can use the ":" to substitute strings in expanded result (*the "&" part being a trick to force command execution*)

```
echo %PATH:;=&echo.%
```

**, but like this**:

```
set VAR=PATH
set DELIM=;
set SUBST=echo.

echo %VAR:%DELIM%=&%SUBST%%
```

Well, I hope you get the point. The above is not valid code.

Anyone has a clue?

The example in the question should be considered generic, and not to be taken literally. The question is *can it be done* and *exactly how*?

Comment: Feel free to change the title to something more meaningful...

Comment: There are some ways: 1. `call echo %%VAR:%DELIM%=&%SUBST%%%`, or 2., when [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled, `echo !VAR:%DELIM%=&%SUBST%!`, or 3. `for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("%DELIM%=%SUBST%") do echo !VAR:%%I=&%%J!`. I tend to call something like this "nested variables" by the way... And there is a typo, it is `SUBST` but not `SUBS`...

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401317) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44687985) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41122788)...

Comment: @aschipfl
Thanks.
All I get is `VAR:;=` in both 1., and 2.
As for 3., that's a flow control, so it doesn't address the question.

Comment: @aschipfl +1 for the links, though.

Comment: Argh, sorry, I missed the `VAR`/`PATH` part: 1. `call echo %%%VAR%:%DELIM%=&%SUBST%%%`, or 2., when delayed expansion is enabled, `echo !%VAR%:%DELIM%=&%SUBST%!`, or 3. `for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:=" %%H in ("%VAR%:%DELIM%=%SUBST%") do echo !%%H:%%I=&%%J!` (also with delayed expansion)...

Comment: No, my very blunt mistake. I forgot to change the variables in the actuall command, while changing them in the declarations. It was due to localized names which would not be understood. But, FYR, 
`call echo %%%VAR%:%DELIM%=&%SUBST%%%` yields 
`PATH:;=\n&` ("\n" is for the actual CRLF)

Comment: Before we go on, I will definitely read your posts in the links. It seems like you are well-versed in cmd language